# How do you read rows from a csv file and store it in an array using Python codes?

Tags: python, arrays, csv, row, jupyter

I have a CSV file, [diseases_matrix_KNN.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfRtn.jpg) which has excel table. 
Now, I would like to store all the numbers from the row like:

```
Hypothermia = [0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

For some reason, I am unable to find a solution to this. 
Even though I have looked. Please let me know if I can read this type of data in the chosen form, using Python please.

Comment: Take a look at the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module.

Comment: You don't find many perfectly completed solutions on line.  You need to learn to analyze your problem and identify solutions steps, then look up how to do each step.  This one requires you to first learn to read a CSV file, then to gather numbers from a single line.  Later, you may find how to combine those steps.

Comment: Consider `pandas`.'

Answer (score 0):

most common way to work with excel is use Pandas.
Here is example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(filename)
print (df.iloc['Hypothermia']). # gives you such result
```